# PCI-e v2.0 video card in a PCI-e v1.0 slot?

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will a PCI-E V2.0 Graphics Card work with a PCI-E V1.0 Motherboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/14709/will-a-pci-e-v2-0-graphics-card-work-with-a-pci-e-v1-0-motherboard)

Will a PCI-e 2.0 card work in a PCI-e 1.0 motherboard?

Currently I've got an older ASUS M2N-E motherboard, and I would like get a newer video card (GTX 280 or similar) which will last me a while after I upgrade my motherboard at some point in the future.  I currently have a 6600 GT which has served me well for a long time, but it's time to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will work in your mother board. PCI-e 2 is backwards compatible with PCI-e 1x. Check your PSU to be to make sure it can supply the require wattage. Here are NVIDIA's [complete spces for the GTX 280](http://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/55506/GPU_Datasheet.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand it is supposed to work, but of course only at 1.0 speeds.

Answer (score 1):

See this thread, the slots are cross compatible.

http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/251704-33-pcie

.